# Variable Annotation repetition

Tags: python, annotations, naming-conventions, type-hinting, python-typing

If we first assign a value to a certain variable and then modify that value (while still keeping the same data type) is it more correct to annotate the expression only the first time or to do it also when we modify the value?

Annotation repeated both times:

```
var: np.array = np.array([...])
var: np.array = var[:,1:].T #Array modification
```

Annotation repeated only once:

```
var: np.array = np.array([...])
var = var[:,1:].T #Array modification
```

Which of the two is the best one?

Comment: Neither.  The standard style is to only annotate when the type of the variable can't be inferred based on its initialization, e.g. if you initialize an empty list and need to annotate what type of objects the list is allowed to contain.  If you initialize `var = np.array([...])` it's obvious that the type of `var` is `np.array` without any annotation needed.  (If you use `mypy` to check types, it will let you know when an annotation is needed -- I'd say 99% of the time all you ever need to annotate are function signatures and everything else can be inferred.)

Comment: So, in this example, if the variable were to be initialized without its datatype being clear, would the second option be preferable?

Comment: Yes; any given variable only ever has one type (which is determined when the variable is declared -- from that point on any attempt to change it is considered a type checking error), so you only ever need to annotate it once (at most).  If you need to assign values of different types to a single variable over the course of a function, then you need to downcast it to an appropriately broad type (e.g. a `Union` of all its eventual possible types) at declaration; you can't declare it as one type and then annotate it as another type later.

Comment: To stress an important point: if you're using type annotations, you should be using `mypy` (since a big part of the point of type annotations is that you can use static analysis to verify that the code matches the annotations), and if you're using `mypy` as you write your code, you'll very quickly discover where you do and don't need annotations.  :)